# Slick2d play audio at half speed leaving pitch unchanged

Tags: java, audio, slick2d, openal

Currently, in Slick2d, if I define a sound,

```
Sound s = new Sound("/res/music/concertAPiano.wav");
s.play(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the speed of the sound. If I set the pitch to lower, I can get the sound to last longer, but obviously this comes at a cost, because it doesn't sound the same. Is there a way that anybody knows of to play a sound in slick at a lower speed at the same pitch?

Comment: Hey, Keon. I was wondering if you were able to figure out a solution for your audio here using Slick2d. I'd be interested to know if you did. If you did figure something out then you can leave an answer and then accept that answer so others can easily find a solution to questions like yours. If a previous answer helped you then you can also accept that answer so others may find a solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with Slick2d's Sound class, and I'm not sure of any audio class in slick that can, unfortunately.

Unless you're going to be needing to change the pitch of this particular sound often within your program it might be better to pull the clip into audio editing software like audacity and you can get your desired effect by using that.

Keep in mind though that the audio may sound distorted or weird because of the nature of music being a wave. It's going to be either stretched or condensed, and this wavelength is responsible for controlling the pitch and speed of the sound.

Check out this post maybe if you want to know more: 
[Is pitch and speed the same thing in audio programming context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775482/is-pitch-and-speed-the-same-thing-in-audio-programming-context?rq=1)